# When to show the view in winform MVP pattern

Tags: .net, winforms, mvp

I am wondering where to call the ShowDialog() in MVP pattern, Presenter is normally defined as:

```
public Presenter(IView view, IModel model)
{
    this.View = view;
    this.View.Presenter = this;
    this.Model = model;
}
```

And I wanna show the View Modelly by calling ShowDialog(), then where should I call the ShowDialog()?

```
public void Foo()
{
var view = New View();
view.ShowDialog();
var presenter = new Presenter(view, model);
}
```

But if i call `ShowDialog()` before the presenter is created, the `.ShowDialog()` will not return before the view is closed,
then I have to call it in `Presenter`, but i feel it anti-pattern  to call `ShowDialog()` in presenter,

So, what's the better solution or is it ok to call ShowDialog() in presenter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not

```
var presenter = new Presenter(view, model);
view.ShowDialog();
```

And no, I don't think calling the ShowDialog in the Presenter is an anti-pattern